# Add multiple images on Frappe DocType field

Tags: image, erpnext, frappe

I want to add multiple images to the Frappe DocType field. I have made a DocType and have a field name image. In this field, I want to add multiple images from users.
I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image filed` will have only one image at a time you cannot upload multiple images to the image filed. Instead, create a `child doctype` with an `image field` and you can create multiple rows to upload an image.

Or else you can use `Attachments` which appears on the left sidebar to upload multiple images

[image]

Comment: thank you I am using child doctype and it works for me.

Comment: @shuvroBaset in my env I want to add multiple photos to Lead. So I created a Doc named Lead Photos, added single field Item of type Attach Image, but unfortunatelly don't know what next. Could U please explain Ur approach in details?

Comment: @qba-dev I have mentioned in the answer that there are no options to add multiple images in a single field. so you have already created a doc named lead photos. when you want to add some data in that doctype form or any saved document you will see the attachment option as I showed in the screenshot. Please check that again. If something is wrong then let me know.